# How to resample relative to first date?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

My series:

```
dates = pd.date_range('2018-01-03', '2018-09-13')
s = pd.Series(range(len(dates)), index=dates)
```

I want to resample to months but starting from first date of index and not from first day of month. If I resample to "MS", first date is 2018-01-01, not 2018-01-03. Of course it's "month start" so that's expected.

But how can I resample monthly without samples being picked from start of month, but rather from the same month day so resulting index is ["2018-01-03", "2018-02-03", etc.] (month starting from first datetime in the index)?

Only way I found is create leading dates, do a negative shift, then use loffset parameter (because neither shift nor loffset respect alignment of the data to index). But this I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Get a monthly series

```
dates = pd.date_range(s.index.min(), s.index.max(), freq='M')
```

Go back to MonthEnd prior to first date and add number of days

```
dates = dates + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(-1) + pd.offsets.Day(s.index[0].day)
```

Use `reindex`

```
s.reindex(dates)

2018-01-03      0
2018-02-03     31
2018-03-03     59
2018-04-03     90
2018-05-03    120
2018-06-03    151
2018-07-03    181
2018-08-03    212
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me, because it doesn't let me aggregate the data in each period, differently from what I can do with "resample"

Answer (score 0):

Building on your response, to reduce the calculations you could do:

```
dates = pd.date_range('2018-01-03', '2018-09-13')
s = pd.Series(range(len(dates)), index=dates)
resampled = s.resample('MS', loffset=pd.Timedelta(days=s.index[0].day) - 1)
```

Please note that I do not copy to S2 and assign a full month index because resample already sets the initial date to the 1st of the month.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I managed to do this was:

From your initial example:

```py
dates = pd.date_range('2018-01-03', '2018-09-13')
s = pd.Series(range(len(dates)), index=dates)

s.resample("30D", origin="start").sum()
```

```
2018-01-03     435
2018-02-02    1335
2018-03-04    2235
2018-04-03    3135
2018-05-03    4035
2018-06-02    4935
2018-07-02    5835
2018-08-01    6735
2018-08-31    3451
Freq: 30D, dtype: int64
```

I know this question is old, I'm on Pandas 2.0.2

Answer (score 0):

*(Solution by OP, originally posted in the question body instead of as a new answer.)*

I solved this by these simple steps, adapting from a number of attempts to fix this issue (including the [answer of piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52526492/), but also other sites and questions from SO):

```py
dates = pd.date_range('2018-01-03', '2018-09-13')
s = pd.Series(range(len(dates)), index=dates)
delta = dates.min() - (dates.min() - offsets.MonthBegin(1))
new_dates = dates - delta
s2 = s.copy()
s2.index = new_dates
resampled = s2.resample('MS', loffset=delta)
r_max = resampled.max()
r_min = resampled.min()
r_mean = resampled.mean()
r_sum = resampled.sum()

print('s\n', s)
print('r_max\n', r_max)
print('r_min\n', r_min)
print('r_mean\n', r_mean)
print('r_sum\n', r_sum)
```

### Alternative solution

I ended up taking a bit of a different approach at this. I start with something like:

```py
dates = pd.date_range('2015-01-31', '2018-09-13')
start_date: dt.date = dates[0].date()
end_date: dt.date = dates[-1].date()
recurrent_dates = []
next_date = start_date
while next_date <= end_date:
    if next_date.day < start_date.day:
        try:
            next_date = dt.date(
                next_date.year, next_date.month, start_date.day)
        except ValueError:
            next_date = (
                    next_date + offsets.MonthBegin(1) - offsets.Day(1)
            ).date()
    recurrent_dates.append(next_date)
    next_date += relativedelta(months=1)
```

To have expected monthly periods starting at arbitrary dates, then create a DataFrame with the recurrent dates above, then reindex it with the dates from the original DataFrame with `fillna(method="ffill")`, then use `groupby` to group by the repeated dates.

Hope this helps other people too.